# Choosing suitable options for solver ODE in JULIA

Tags: performance, julia, numerical-methods, ode

I want to ask you please which options and solver is the most suitable for solving the ODE system shown, as you can see I tried different options but the results that I obtained were not the same, so I want to know what could be the best option for solving this ODE system please. The main problem is related with the fact that I want to determine the steady state solution for longer times where the solvers differ. Thanks.

```julia
using DifferentialEquations
using Plots; plotly() 

#Parameters

omega_m     = 1.6e6         
N           = 1
Delta_mw    = -0.7           
g0          = 3.6e3#/omega_m 
g_eff       = (g0/sqrt(N))
Gamma       = 60000#/omega_m
Gamma_tilde = 0.0       
Omega_mw    = 0.7           
Q           = 2*(10^5)
gamma_m     = (omega_m/Q) #/ omega_m
N_th        = 6.05
Angle_th    = 0;
tau         = (Gamma/(g_eff^2));
#omega_m     = 1 

function mean_field(du,u,p,t)
    
    
    #p[1]=Delta_mw
    #p[2]=Omega_mw
      
    Sx     =u[1]
    Sy     =u[2]
    Sz     =u[3]
    alpha_x=u[4]
    alpha_y=u[5]
        
    du[1] =  (Delta_mw-4*g_eff*u[4])*u[2]                 - (Gamma+Gamma_tilde)*u[1]
    du[2] = -(Delta_mw-4*g_eff*u[4])*u[1]  -Omega_mw*u[3] - (Gamma+Gamma_tilde)*u[2]
    du[3] =                                 Omega_mw*u[2] - 2*Gamma*(u[3]+N)
    du[4] =  omega_m*u[5]                                 - (gamma_m /2)*u[4]
    du[5] = -omega_m*u[4]                  -g_eff*u[3]    - (gamma_m /2)*u[5]

    
    
    
    #du[1] =  (p[1]-4*g_eff*alpha_x)*Sy          - (Gamma+Gamma_tilde)*Sx
    #du[2] = -(p[1]-4*g_eff*alpha_x)*Sx -p[2]*Sz - (Gamma+Gamma_tilde)*Sy
    #du[3] =                             p[2]*Sy - 2*Gamma*(Sz+N)
    #du[4] =  omega_m*alpha_y                    - (gamma_m /2)*alpha_x
    #du[5] = -omega_m*alpha_x - g_eff*Sz         - (gamma_m /2)*alpha_y
    
    end  


function Result_lim(Array_sol)
    
    print((Array_sol[2][4])^2+(Array_sol[2][5])^2,"     ")
end

#Initial state

u0 = [0;0;-N;sqrt(N_th);0];
time= 100*tau

function Quanta_fin(Delta_mw,Omega_mw)
    
    parameters=[Delta_mw ;Omega_mw ]
    tspan = (0.0,time)
    prob = ODEProblem(mean_field,u0,tspan,parameters)   #,parameters)
    
    Val1=1e-6
    Val2=1e-6
    Iter=1e14
    dt_size=1e-7
 
    sol1 = solve(prob,RK4(),dt=dt_size,save_everystep=false,reltol=Val1,abstol=Val2,MaxIters=Iter)
    sol2 = solve(prob,alg_hints=[:stiff],dt=dt_size,reltol=Val1,abstol=Val2,save_everystep=false,MaxIters=Iter)
    sol3 = solve(prob,Rodas4() ,dt=dt_size,reltol=Val1,abstol=Val2,save_everystep=false,MaxIters=Iter)
    sol4 = solve(prob,EulerHeun() ,dt=dt_size,reltol=Val1,abstol=Val2,save_everystep=false,MaxIters=Iter)
    sol5 = solve(prob,OwrenZen5() ,dt=dt_size,reltol=Val1,abstol=Val2,save_everystep=false,MaxIters=Iter)
    sol6 = solve(prob,TanYam7() ,dt=dt_size,reltol=Val1,abstol=Val2,save_everystep=false,MaxIters=Iter)
    sol7 = solve(prob,alg_hints=[:nonstiff] ,dt=dt_size,reltol=Val1,abstol=Val2,save_everystep=false,MaxIters=Iter)

    
    Array_sol1=sol1.u
    Array_sol2=sol2.u
    Array_sol3=sol3.u
    Array_sol4=sol4.u
    Array_sol5=sol5.u
    Array_sol6=sol6.u
    Array_sol7=sol7.u


    Result_lim(Array_sol1)
    Result_lim(Array_sol2)
    Result_lim(Array_sol3)
    Result_lim(Array_sol4)
    Result_lim(Array_sol5)
    Result_lim(Array_sol6)
    Result_lim(Array_sol7)

    
    end


Quanta_fin(-Delta_mw,Omega_mw)
```

The results obtained were in the order suggested by the code:

```
4.03957009141576   3.405161284931335   3.4050247554548427
0.397414473765911  2.8927830118053133  0.2714810985447397
0.397414473765911
```

Comment: You have a very rapid oscillation in components 4,5 due to `omega_m     = 1.6e6`. To get a sufficient sampling you need a sampling frequency of at least `1e7`, 6 points per period, better would be 20 points, meaning your step size is barely inside the admissible range. That will be corrected for the adaptive methods, but is critical for the fixed-step methods RK4 and Heun. It might be worthwhile to renormalize the scales of the components, so that the absolute error has about the same influence on all of them. You might also try a smaller value for the relative error.

Comment: Thanks @LutzLehmann, I would try this for sure.